# УмнО, хитрО

Tags: фонетика

Не раз слышала с экрана телевизора эти слова именно с таким ударением. Употреблялись они в контексте оценки. Например, как оценка поступка: "УмнО!"
Допустимо ли такое ударение в принципе?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Допустимо, и не только в качестве наречия (если это наречие, то только такое ударение). В качестве краткого прилагательного словари допускают двоякое ударение: Умно и умнО. Почти то же  и со словом "хитро". Двоякое ударение возможно и в прилагательном, и в наречии.

Comment: >Допустимо ли такое ударение в принципе?

Полагаю, что такое ударение не *в принципе* и не с допущением *по вкусу*, а при конкретной оценке выбирается умышленно для выражения иронии. Именно, как маркер, обозначающий наличие оснований для сомнений в адекватности ответа, объяснения, предложения, поступка... Одним лишь переносом ударения может быть выражен разный по ситуации умалчиваемый комментарий: а) спасибо,кэп, б) за морем телушка — полушка, да рубль перевоз, в) гладко было на бумаге, да забыли про овраги... И т. п.